# Hide the outside element on click of parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head> 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <body>
     <div class="product details product-item-details">
     <div class="swatch-option text" >Large</div>
       <div class="price-box price-final_price">
           <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">        
            <span class="price-label" style="display: 
           inline;">From</span>100</span>

          </div> 
     </div>

   <div class="product details product-item-details">
     <div class="swatch-option text" >Large</div>
     <div class="price-box price-final_price">
          <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">     
            <span class="price-label" style="display: inline;">From</span>200</span>

        </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="product details product-item-details">
     <div class="swatch-option text" >Large</div>
     <div class="price-box price-final_price">
          <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">     
            <span class="price-label" style="display: inline;">From</span>300</span>

          </div> 
  </div>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function($){
     $('.product-item-details .swatch-option').live("click",function(){ 
        $(this).next('.price-final_price .price-container .price-label').hide();

    });
  });
  <script>

 </body>
</head>  
</html>
```

I need to hide "From" label of the span element "price-label" when a particular div is clicked.

The above jQuery code is not working for me,

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, dont use `.live` but use `.on` because `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated.`

Then use `$(this).next('.price-final_price').find(".price-container .price-label").hide();`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.product-item-details .swatch-option').on("click", function() {
    $(this).next('.price-final_price').find(".price-container .price-label").hide();
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.product-item-details .swatch-option').on("click", function() {
    $(this).next('.price-final_price').find(".price-container .price-label").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product details product-item-details">
  <div class="swatch-option text">Large</div>
  <div class="price-box price-final_price">
    <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">        
            <span class="price-label" style="display: 
           inline;">From</span>100</span>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="product details product-item-details">
  <div class="swatch-option text">Large</div>
  <div class="price-box price-final_price">
    <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">     
            <span class="price-label" style="display: inline;">From</span>200</span>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="product details product-item-details">
  <div class="swatch-option text">Large</div>
  <div class="price-box price-final_price">
    <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">     
            <span class="price-label" style="display: inline;">From</span>300</span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Also, your '.next' is taking just next sibling, but what you need is to take, 
".price-container .price-label" of '.price-final_price'
So the correct way is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.swatch-option').on("click", function() {
        $(this).next('.price-final_price').find(".price-container .price-label").hide();
  });
});
```

Also, some suggestions :

1. You are using jquery/3.2.1/

I suggest using 3.4.1 "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js

2. You included everything inside your 'head' tag.
   I suggest to limit it with only scripts, like so :

```
<head> 
  <script deffer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script deffer src="yourjQueryFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourCssFile.css">
</head>  
<body>
  {Your code here}
</body>
```

You can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/The_head_metadata_in_HTML

3. Separate JS HTML and CSS files, and then include them into the  tag, as shown above. The modular way is always better and cleaner.

JSFiddle [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p1t8dfwv/)

Answer (score -1):

**please try this code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.product-item-details .swatch-option').click(function(){ 
            
           $(this).next().find('.price-label').hide();
         });
      });
   </script>
  </head>
 <body>
   <div class="product details product-item-details">
      <div class="swatch-option text" >Large</div>
      <div class="price-box price-final_price">
         <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">        
         <span class="price-label" style="display: inline;">From</span>100</span>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="product details product-item-details">
     <div class="swatch-option text" >Large</div>
     <div class="price-box price-final_price">
         <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">     
         <span class="price-label" style="display: inline;">From</span>200</span>
      </div> 
   </div>

   <div class="product details product-item-details">
      <div class="swatch-option text" >Large</div>
      <div class="price-box price-final_price">
         <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">     
         <span class="price-label" style="display: inline;">From</span>300</span>
      </div> 
   </div>
   
   
 </body>
</head>  
</html>
```